# Joomla 3.1 - how to create a component with tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, joomla3.1

I am creating a component for Joomla that uses some tables.
In the DB side of the component, I just wanted to know of there is any restriction from Joomla DB on the relations between tables.
I got a freelancer who told me that is impossible to manage tables with foreign keys and tables relations in Joomla Database.

I just wanted to know if it is right or not.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He is wrong. There is nothing really that Joomla can not do that you would be able to do with php.

Even the [Joomla Component Creator](http://www.component-creator.com) can create components with foreign keys and it is Joomla 3.1 ready so maybe give that a try.